# Can I run a test in a loop in Ceedling?

Tags: c, unit-testing, unity-test-framework

I'm pretty new to using Ceedling/Unity. I have a module I'm testing by giving it different input test points and checking the output value. But I need to do this many times. This is something like what I tried (using 'for' loop):

```
/*Example Code*/
void test_whenInputIsThis_thenOutputIsThat(void)
{
    for(i=0;i<ITERATIONS;i++)
    {
    /*Everything is declared & initialized as required*/
    inputA = inputA_array[i];
    inputB = inputB_array[i];
    expected = expectedValues_array[i];
    ModuleUnderTest(inputA, inputB);
    TEST_ASSERT_FLOAT_WITHIN(delta, expected, actual);
    }
}
```

And although I see the tests passed (expected and actual are within delta), in the Overall Test Summary I see this

```
--------------------
OVERALL TEST SUMMARY
--------------------
TESTED:  1
PASSED:  1
FAILED:  0
IGNORED: 0
```

This suggests to me that one test function = 1 test. Interestingly, I can print all values for expected and actual through the loop (so the loop is executing fully). So, is there a way to put a test in a loop? Or iterate it some other way? Or am I breaking some rule of unit testing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning Ceedling but generally test runners treat each function they find as one test. If you have a static array of test inputs and outputs you could write a helper function without the test_ prefix in your test file like

```
void runMyTest(int index)
{
    float delta = MIN_DELTA;
    actual = ModuleUnderTest(inputA_array[index], inputB_array[index]);
    TEST_ASSERT_FLOAT_WITHIN(delta, expected[index], actual);
}

void test_state1(void)
{
    runMyTest(1);
}

void test_state2(void)
{
    runMyTest(2);
}

void test_state3(void)
{
    runMyTest(3);
}
```

This will give you three separate tests.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried this and it works great!